# Difference between SWIFT Interact & Fileact transmissions

Tags: edi, banking, eai, b2b, swift-mt

Can you please help me to understand the difference between SWIFT Interact & Fileact protocol

Answer (score 2):

The two products are designed to handle *different* types of financial *processing*.

SWIFT Interact is designed for solutions where a real-time gross settlement system is in play, better known by its acronym RTGS. This type of processing is near real-time processing. In the US the FedWIRE for example is an RTGS solution.

The SWIFT Fileact is used for time-insensitive processing, i.e. batch processing. In such a system, financial transactions are queued up and then batch processed at a particular time. For example ACH is a batch processed system.

Though both protocols are handling financial transactions, the difference lies in the *processing handling* aspect of it.

Answer (score -3):

@venkat

If you are looking for more information about OpenStack Swift kindly follow our developer documentation http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/ for details.